# How to runtime insert into ReserveCost table in a basic MSI project in InstallShield through custom action?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I want to insert a row into `ReserveCost` table through a custom action. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need this? It's a very unusual approach.

Comment: actualy i am installing prerequisites in my setup like .Net Framework, Languagepack,etc., and in DiskSpaceRequirement dialog doesn't calculate space required for prerequisites...
So i want to manually add space in ReserveCost table....:)

Comment: That's not a good idea. Prerequisites handle their own requirements. You would be reserving space for nothing.

Comment: no.. it doesn't work.... because i am having feature prerequisites and not setup prerequisites, so it displays space which is occupied by my program files folder, it doesn't count the space for prerequisites...
:(

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. Cost of prerequisites will be handled within their respective setups/components. If you add that to your installer, it will actually show a wrong number.